# How to access parent pom properties in spring boot project

Tags: maven, spring-boot, maven-3

This is my spring boot pom ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.piggymetrics</groupId>
    <artifactId>gateway</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>gateway</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cc.cmt.ccc</groupId>
            <artifactId>cc.ccme</artifactId>
            <version>${cc.cmt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>Brixton.M4</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

I have a parent pom ,which contain one properties version ${cc.cmt.version} ,How could I access this ?

Comment: You don't have a parent containing that version at least I highly doubt that the `spring-boot-starter-parent` contains that version property.

Comment: No I have a different parent pom ,which contains this property

Comment: You don't. At least not in this project as that isn't the parent... The fact that you have another project/pom lying around with that property doesn't make it a parent pom or whatever.

Comment: The question is why not just writing the version simply in the pom file?

Comment: that I can do ,keeping all these properties in parent pom and trying to access in child pom .As spring boot already contain one parent ,unable to inherit the parent ,is there any other option ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you want to deal with has more to do with Maven itself than of Spring Boot. If my assumption is right, you're likely in following situation

- ModuleA

  - ModuleB
  - ModuleC

where, as depicted, say, there're three Maven modules in your Spring Boot project. You'd like to inherit `ModuleA` in the pom.xml of `ModuleB` and both of them needs to have Spring Boot parent dependency.

Maven project's can't have multiple parents declared in one pom.xml. Having said that, the workaround here is to declare `org.springframework.boot` parent dependency at `ModuleA` first along with all other property values. Now, just declare `ModuleA` as parent in the pom.xml of `ModuleB`and `ModuleB` will be able to access all dependencies(Spring Boot+others) as well as properties declared in `ModuleA`'s pom.xml.